# Google spreadsheets: how to merge two sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Say I have a sheet1 (first image below) and a sheet2 (second image below).

How can I automatically merge two sheets into one as in the third image below? E.g. unchanged cells should be put directly. If a cell is changed, both old and new values should be put to the cell as shown.

[image: first]

[image: second]

[image: third]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=if(Sheet1!A1 = Sheet2!A1, Sheet1!A1, "old:"&Sheet1!A1&" new"&Sheet2!A1) If you copied that into all 4 cells on sheet3, b4 would display "old: fourth new: fifth"

Comment: The actual sheets are much bigger. So I do not want to write each cell one by one. I need an automatic way to populate the third sheet. Notice the lower right cell in the third sheet. Its value comes from sheet1 and sheet2. Other cell values come either from sheet1 or sheet2, which does not matter as they are the same.

Comment: Could you be more specific?  I don't follow exactly what you're wanting from your example.

Comment: Is this what you mean?
=if(Sheet1!A1 = Sheet2!A1, Sheet1!A1, "old:"&Sheet1!A1&" new"&Sheet2!A1)
If you copied that into all 4 cells on sheet3, b4 would display "old: fourth new: fifth"